# Discord bot does not respond to pressing the button

Tags: discord, disnake

import disnake

from disnake.ext import commands

from collections import defaultdict

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned)

interactions = defaultdict(MyModal)

class MyModal(disnake.ui.Modal):

```
def __init__(self) -> None:

    components = [

        disnake.ui.TextInput(

            label="Ваш ник:",

            placeholder="Введите ваш никнейм",

            custom_id="никнейм",

            style=disnake.TextInputStyle.single_line,

            min_length=1,

            max_length=50,

        ),

        disnake.ui.TextInput(

            label="Ссылка на скриншот подарка:",

            placeholder="Вставьте ссылку на скриншот подарка",

            custom_id="скриншот",

            style=disnake.TextInputStyle.paragraph,

            min_length=1,

            max_length=1024,

        ),

    ]

    super().__init__(title="Create Tag", custom_id="create_tag", components=components)

async def callback(self, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction) -> None:

    nick_name = inter.text_values["никнейм"]

    screenshot_link = inter.text_values["скриншот"]

    embed = disnake.Embed(title=f"Заявка на роль от `{nick_name}`")

    embed.add_field(name="Ссылка на скриншот подарка", value=screenshot_link)

    # Отправка результатов в указанный канал

    if self.result_channel:

        await self.result_channel.send(embed=embed)

    await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

@bot.event

async def on_interaction(inter: disnake.Interaction):

```
if isinstance(inter, disnake.MessageInteraction):

    if inter.message.components and inter.data['custom_id'] == "open_form_button":

        # Создаем модальное окно и указываем канал для результатов

        modal = interactions[inter.message.id]

        modal.result_channel_id = 900354293155123252

        # Отправляем сообщение с модальным окном

        components = [disnake.ui.ActionRow(modal.components)]

        message = await inter.channel.send("Открываем форму заявки...", components=components)

        interactions[message.id] = modal
```

@bot.event

async def on_button_click(inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):

```
if inter.message.id in interactions:

    # Обрабатываем взаимодействие кнопки в контексте модального окна

    await interactions[inter.message.id].button_callback(inter)
```

@bot.slash_command()

async def заявка(inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):

```
result_channel_id = 900354293155123252  # ID канала для результатов

modal = interactions[inter.message.id]

modal.result_channel = bot.get_channel(result_channel_id)

button_message = await inter.channel.send("Нажмите кнопку, чтобы открыть форму заявки!", components=[

    disnake.ui.Button(label="Открыть форму", custom_id="open_form_button")])
```

@bot.event

async def on_ready():

```
print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})\n------")
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

I tried a lot of things, the bot had to open a form with questions by clicking on the button